# How to show the continuity of the Laplacian of the heat kernel (in t)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let  $K_t(x):=(4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}$ be the heat kernel for $t > 0$. How can I show that the function $t \mapsto (\Delta K_t)*f$ is continuous in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (associated with the $L^p$ norm) for $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ?

I have proven the the continuity of this function $t \mapsto(\Delta K_t)*f(x)$ for every $x$ but clearly this is not sufficient.
I have that $\lvert| \Delta K_t |\rvert_{1}\leq \frac{d}{2t}+ \frac{1}{2}(4 \pi t)^{-d/2}(\frac{\pi}{t})^{1/2}$, but I can't find the correct bound function to use this.

Comment: This may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks. Indeed, that's the way but I forgot the Laplacian in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t_n, t>0$ such that $t_n \to t$. Then we have

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708255/uniform-convergence-of-the-laplacian-of-heat-kernel) $\| \Delta K_{t_n} - \Delta K_{t}\|_\infty \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} 0$.

By [Young's inequality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Young%27s_convolution_inequality#Statement),
$$
\begin{align}
\| (\Delta K_{t_n})*f - (\Delta K_t)*f \|_{\infty} &= \| (\Delta K_{t_n} - \Delta K_t)*f \|_{\infty} \\
&\le \| \Delta K_{t_n} - \Delta K_t \|_\infty \|f\|_{L^1}.
\end{align}
$$

The claim then follows from above **Lemma**.

Comment: Hey Analyst, thank you for your answer.  Don't we need $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1+\frac{1}{r}$ in order to apply Young ? We need to work with an $L^1$ norm.

Comment: @G__C You are right! I have edited my answer.

Comment: All right @Analyst, but how can this be applied to a general p ? I mean don't we only get the convergence on $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ?

Comment: Indeed, I have just [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708255/uniform-convergence-of-the-laplacian-of-heat-kernel/4708617#4708617) $\| \Delta K_{t_n} - \Delta K_{t}\|_{L^p} \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} 0$ for any $p \in [1, \infty)$. Then you can apply Young's inequality to get your desired result.