# Uniform convergence of heat kernel

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, alternative-proof

For $t>0$, we define
$$
g_t:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}, x \mapsto  e^{- |x|^2 /t}.
$$

In solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705124/how-to-show-the-continuity-of-the-laplacian-of-the-heat-kernel-in-t) question about heat kernel, I have to verify the following lemma, i.e.,

> Let $t_n, t >0$ such that $t_n \to t$ as $n \to +\infty$. Then $g_{t_n} \to g_t$ uniformly as $n \to +\infty$.

1. Could you have a check on my attempt?
2. Are there other approaches?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

By mean value theorem, for each $x \in \mathbb R^d$, there is $t_{n, x}$ between $t_n$ and $t$ such that
$$
\begin{align}
g_{t_n} (x) - g_t (x) &= e^{- |x|^2 /t_n} - e^{- |x|^2 /t} \\
&= \frac{|x|^2}{t_{n, x}^2} e^{- |x|^2 /t_{n, x}} (t_n - t) \\
&= \frac{|x|^2}{t_{n, x}} e^{- |x|^2 /t_{n, x}} \frac{t_n - t}{t_{n, x}}.
\end{align}
$$

We have $\sup_{h \ge 0} he^{-h} \le \frac{1}{e} < 1$. Then
$$
|g_{t_n} (x) - g_t (x)| \le \frac{t_n - t}{t_{n, x}}
\quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^d.
$$

WLOG, we assume $\alpha :=\inf_n t_n >0$. Then
$$
|g_{t_n} (x) - g_t (x)| \le \frac{t_n - t}{\alpha}
\quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^d.
$$

The claim then follows.

Comment: Did you mean to use $\alpha = \inf_{n \in \mathbb Z_+, x \in \mathbb R^d} t_{n, x}$?

Comment: @0XLR I think  $\alpha :=\inf_n t_n$ is enough because $t_{n, x}$ is always between $t_n$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the same strategy, we can proved that $\|g_{t_n} - g_t\|_{L^p} \to 0$ for $p \in [1, \infty)$.

---

For $t>0$, we define $f_t:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
f_t (x) := \frac{|x|^{2}}{t} \exp \bigg ( -\frac{|x|^{2}}{t} \bigg )
$$

Then
$$
g_{t_n} (x) - g_t (x) = f_{t_{n, x}} (x) \frac{t_n - t}{t_{n, x}}.
$$

WLOG, we assume there are $0<a<b<\infty$ such that $t_n \in [a, b]$ for all $n$. Then $t_{n, x} \in [a, b]$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x\in \mathbb R^d$. Then
$$
\|g_{t_n} - g_t\|_{L^p} \le \frac{|t_n - t|}{a} \sup_{t \in [a, b]} \|f_t\|_{L^p}
$$

We can [prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708601/how-to-prove-sup-t-in-a-b-int-mathbb-rd-f-t-xp-mathrm-d-x) that
$$
\sup_{t \in [a, b]} \|f_t\|^p_{L^p} =\sup_{t \in [a, b]} \int_{\mathbb R^d} |f_t (x)|^p \, \mathrm d x < \infty.
$$

Then claim then follows.