# Uniform convergence of the Laplacian of heat kernel

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, alternative-proof, heat-equation

We consider the heat kernel
$$
g :\mathbb R_{>0} \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R, (t, x) \mapsto \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

Let $t_n, \bar t >0$ such that $t_n \to \bar t$ as $n \to +\infty$. In order to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705124/how-to-show-the-continuity-of-the-laplacian-of-the-heat-kernel-in-t) question about heat kernel, I have to verify

> $\Delta g(t, \cdot) \to \Delta g (\bar t, \cdot)$ uniformly as $n \to +\infty$.

1. Could you have a check on my attempt?
2. Are there other approaches?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

We have
$$
\Delta g(t, x) =  \left(\frac{|x|^2-2 d t}{4 t^2}\right) g(t, x).
$$

I have already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708211/uniform-convergence-of-heat-kernel) that $g (t_n, \cdot) \to g(\bar t, \cdot)$ uniformly as $n \to +\infty$. It suffices to prove that
$$
\frac{|\cdot|^2}{t_n^2} g(t_n, \cdot) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} \frac{|\cdot|^2}{\bar t^2} g(\bar t, \cdot)
\quad \text{uniformly}.
$$

We have
$$
\frac{|x|^2}{t^2} g(t, x) = \frac{|x|^2}{t^2 (4\pi t)^{d/2}} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

We define
$$
h :\mathbb R_{>0} \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R, (t, x) \mapsto \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$
h(t_n, \cdot) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} h(\bar t, \cdot)
\quad \text{uniformly}.
$$

We have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, x) = \frac{|x|^4}{16t^3} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ) - \frac{|x|^2}{4t^2} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

WLOG, we assume there are $\alpha, \beta>0$ such that $\alpha \le t_n \le \beta$ for all $n$. Any polynomial function is dominated by exponential function, so
$$
\gamma :=\sup_{t \in [\alpha, \beta], x \in \mathbb R^d} \bigg | \frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, x) \bigg | <+\infty.
$$

By mean value theorem, for each $x \in \mathbb R^d$ there is $t_{n,x}$ between $t_n$ and $t$ such that
$$
h(t_n, x) -h(\bar  t, x)  = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, x) \bigg |_{t=t_{n, x}} (t_n-\bar t).
$$

Then
$$
|h(t_n, x) -h(\bar  t, x)|  \le \gamma|t_n-\bar t|
\quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^d.
$$

The claim then follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the same strategy, we can proved that $\|\Delta g(t, \cdot) - \Delta g (\bar t, \cdot)\|_{L^p} \to 0$ for $p \in [1, \infty)$.

---

We have
$$
\Delta g(t, x) =  \left(\frac{|x|^2-2 d t}{4 t^2}\right) g(t, x).
$$

I have already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4708608/1019043) that $g (t_n, \cdot) \to g(\bar t, \cdot)$ in $L^p$ as $n \to +\infty$. It suffices to prove that
$$
\frac{|\cdot|^2}{t_n^2} g(t_n, \cdot) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} \frac{|\cdot|^2}{\bar t^2} g(\bar t, \cdot)
\quad \text{in} \quad L^p.
$$

We have
$$
\frac{|x|^2}{t^2} g(t, x) = \frac{|x|^2}{t^2 (4\pi t)^{d/2}} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

We define
$$
h :\mathbb R_{>0} \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R, (t, x) \mapsto \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$
h(t_n, \cdot) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} h(\bar t, \cdot)
\quad \text{in} \quad L^p.
$$

By mean value theorem, for each $x \in \mathbb R^d$ there is $t_{n,x}$ between $t_n$ and $t$ such that
$$
h(t_n, x) -h(\bar  t, x)  = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, x) \bigg |_{t=t_{n, x}} (t_n-\bar t).
$$

Then
$$
|h(t_n, x) -h(\bar  t, x)|  \le \bigg | \frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t_{n, x}, x) \bigg| |t_n-\bar t|
\quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^d.
$$

WLOG, we assume there are $0 < a <b<\infty$ such that $t_n \in [a, b]$ for all $n$.
$$
\gamma :=\sup_{t \in [\alpha, \beta], x \in \mathbb R^d} \bigg | \frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, x) \bigg | <+\infty.
$$

Then
$$
\| h(t_n, \cdot) - h(\bar t, \cdot) \|_{L^p} \le |t_n-\bar t| \underbrace{\sup_{t \in [a, b]} \bigg \| \frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, \cdot) \bigg \|_{L^p}}_{\gamma}.
$$

It suffices to prove that $\gamma<\infty$.  We have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, x) = \frac{|x|^4}{16t^3} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ) - \frac{|x|^2}{4t^2} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

Let
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi_t (x) &:= \frac{|x|^4}{16t^3} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ), \\
\psi_t (x) &:= \frac{|x|^2}{4t^2} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
\end{align}
$$

We have
$$
\bigg \| \frac{\partial}{\partial t} h(t, \cdot) \bigg \|_{L^p} \le \|\varphi_t\|_{L^p} + \|\psi_t\|_{L^p}.
$$

Then
$$
\gamma \le \underbrace{\sup_{t \in [a, b]} \|\varphi_t\|_{L^p}}_{\gamma_1} + \underbrace{\sup_{t \in [a, b]} \|\psi_t\|_{L^p}}_{\gamma_2}.
$$

Just as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708601/how-to-prove-sup-t-in-a-b-int-mathbb-rd-f-t-xp-mathrm-d-x) question, we can prove that $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 <\infty$. The claim then follows.